How to decode the response from HW-100KVWP scale via PUSR232TCP?
I am working with the HW-100KVWP weighing scale, connected to a PUSR232TCP device via an RS232 cable. When I press the "Print" button on the scale, I receive the following raw data:
b'\xf8\x80x\x00x\x00x\xf8x\x80\x00\x80\x00\x80\x00\x80\x00\x80\x00\x80\x80x\xf8\x80\x80\xf8\xf8\xf8\x00\xf8\xf8x\xf8\x80x\x00\x80x'
The weight measured at the time was 0.37 KG. I am trying to understand how to decode this response to extract the actual weight value.
The HW-100KVWP is a digital weighing scale that can transmit data via RS232.
I connected the scale to a PUSR232TCP device, which converts the RS232 signal to TCP.
The raw data above was captured from the TCP stream after pressing the "Print" button.
My Questions:
What is the format of the raw data sent by the HW-100KVWP scale?
How can I decode this data to extract the weight value?
Is there any documentation or standard encoding for such devices that I should refer to?
If needed, I can provide more details about the setup or share any additional data captures.
Thank you in advance for any guidance!

First link when I google for "HW-100KVWP scale protocol": https://www.aandd.jp/products/manual/balances/hvw-wp.pdf

In the PDF document mentioned in the previous comment, page 50 (page 48 printed at the bottom) says that data bits are 7 and parity is even. Perhaps you are programming with data bits 8 and no parity? Please review your settings.
